# Importar HTML para DataGridView [C#]

Tags: c#, html, datagridview, html-agility-pack

Estou trabalhando pela primeira vez com o `HtmlAgilityPack` para leitura de um arquivo HTML que estou manipulando. A ideia é pegar determinados dados deste arquivo e inserir nas respectivas colunas do meu `datagridview`.

O código que uso para realizar a leitura e obtenção de cada informação, é este:

```
  string pagina = tb_SourceHTML.Text.Trim();

        var htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(pagina);

        string ClassToGet = "semBorda";


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='" + ClassToGet + "']"))
        {
            string value = node.InnerText;
            dtgridview_ProdutosInventarioInicial.Rows.Add(value);   
        }
```

O arquivo HTML que é lido, é basicamente constituído desta forma:

```
<td width="17%" class="semBorda" height="20">1.1213.0424.003-0</td>
        <td width="50%" class="semBorda" height="20">ALPRAZOLAM</td>
        <td width="18%" class="semBorda" height="20">1601792</td>
        <td width="15%" class="semBorda" height="20">2
</td>

 <td width="17%" class="semBorda" height="20">1.1213.0424.003-0</td>
        <td width="50%" class="semBorda" height="20">ALPRAZOLAM</td>
        <td width="18%" class="semBorda" height="20">1601792</td>
        <td width="15%" class="semBorda" height="20">2
</td>

  .
  .
  .
```

Porém o problema está na parte da inserção.

Atualmente, as informações ficam desta forma após inserir os dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, eu gostaria que, cada informação, de cada tag do `<td>` fosse inserida respectivamente nas colunas do meu `datagridview`. (primeira `<td>`na primeira coluna, segunda `<td>` na segunda coluna e assim sucessivamente).

Desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei inserir no `datagridview` desta forma:

```
string value = node.InnerText;
dtgridview_ProdutosInventarioInicial.Rows.Add(value, value, value);
```

Porém os registros repetem ao invés de ser inserido um de cada vez uma única vez.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: seria mais fácil fazer o SelectNodes por `tr` (row), e depois então dividir por celula (td)... ao fazer Rows.Add() já tem que levar todas as colunas nos parametros... `dtgridview_ProdutosInventarioInicial.Rows.Add(valor_da_coluna1, valor_da_coluna2);`